# What are the list of ini_set() function cannot be overridden by php script?

Tags: php

i do not know whether it is possible to override all ini_set() in php script!. For example, we can able to change the ini_set value for memory_limit using php script. But a friend of mine said, it is not possible to set / change value for some ini_set() in php script . Can anybody list that ini_set() functions?

Sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ini_get_all( null, TRUE);
```

example:

```
    [safe_mode_include_dir] => Array
    (
        [global_value] => 
        [local_value] => 
        [access] => 4
    )
```

**What is access = 4?**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

```
PHP_INI_USER    1 = Entry can be set in user scripts 
                    (like with ini_set()) or in the Windows registry
PHP_INI_PERDIR  6 = Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf
PHP_INI_SYSTEM  4 = Entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf
PHP_INI_ALL     7 = Entry can be set anywhere
```

To answer your question, those access is 1 or 7 can set in php scripts

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation -->

- [ini_set() parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php#refsect1-function.ini-set-parameters)
- [List of init_set() directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).